# Forcing a mvn build failure if a regex is matched

Tags: java, maven

Which is the easiest way to make a `mvn` build fail if certain regex matches the src code?

The best solution I found (hacky) is using the [maven-replacer-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) and use the regex to replace the code with something that generates a compilation failure.

Comment: Could you just write a test that looks at the source with the regex and fails if it matches?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with such kind of regex ? Code conventions?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Notify other developers that certain library method shouldn't be used and another one should be used.

I can't modified that library src code to add the deprecated annotation.

Comment: @TomMcIntyre: Not sure how easy is to get src files from a test without hardcoding the path to files. Any idea regarding that approach?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the [checkstyle-maven-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) where you can add a particular rules for checkstyle. There is also a Eclipse plugin for that.

Comment: May be you can take a look at [findbugs-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/) as well (and the docs) might be an option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Maven Checkstyle Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html).

In my pom I have:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

The `checkstyle.xml` has the following:

```
<module name="Checker">

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
            <property name="format" value="myRegex"/>
            <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
            <property name="message" value="bla bla bla"/>
        </module>
    </module>

</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you are running a test in maven then the project home will be the working directory, so to get the src directory:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src");
```

Then recursively find all .java files under that directory and apply the regex.